# Java method signature throwing same exception (via generics) twice

Tags: java

Case simplified:
Legacy code. 3 exceptions X,Y and ZException. Class A has method `public C fetch(...) throws X and YException` and class B has `public C fetch(...) throws ZException`. The method implementation is almost the same, so I was wondering could I refactor it to some helper class. Method signatures cannot be changed. I came up with the following helper class

```
public class Common<T extends Exception, V extends Exception>{

    public static interface ExceptionSupplier<T extends Exception> {
        public T create();
    }

    private ExceptionSupplier<T> es;
    private ExceptionSupplier<V> es2;

    public Common(ExceptionSupplier<T> es, ExceptionSupplier<V> es2) {
        this.es = es;
        this.es2 = es2;
    }

    public void method() throws T, V {
        //example that would could throw both T and V
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            throw es.create();
        } else {
            throw es2.create();
        }
    }

}
```

Then I can create instance of that Common class in A and B e.g.

```
helper = new CommonThrower<ZException, ZException>(zSupplier, zSupplier);
helper = new CommonThrower<XException, YException>(xSupplier, ySupplier)
```

and call `helper.fetch(...)` and it shows (in eclipse) beging throw correct types. However it will (as somewhat expected) throwing ZException twice.

My question is there any problem having a method signature throws SomeException, SomeException (i.e. declaring the same exception again)? The code compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Generics aren’t the solution.  Make a private method for the common logic;  then make separate public methods which call it and wrap whatever exceptions it throws in X/Y/ZExceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... throws IOException, IOException { ... .

Redundancy is just confusing, but runs fine.

A more common example of redundancy is something like

```
throws StreamCorruptedException, IOException {
```

In this case `StreamCorruptedException` is an `IOException` so it is not needed, but might be included to make it consistent with the Javadoc which might give more details for this exception.

Comment: I'm aware that throwing sub class of other exception is fine, just wondering if there is any problems having the exactly same exception twice e.g. ... throws IOException, IOException { ...   . Normally you would not do this, but in this case it happens if T and V have same exception as parameter. Maybe I'm worrying too much :)

Comment: @BjarneBoström I have updated my answer to make it clearer.